# Submit the values of a listbox to the controller

Tags: c#, forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, I am trying to have a listbox in which the user can add a variable amount of values to, and then submit these values in a collection.

Here is my model:

```
public sealed class TestModel
{
    public IList<string> MyStrings { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitTest(TestModel testModel)
    {
        return Index();
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
@model WebApplication4.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Page";
}
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTest", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" id="testTestbox" />
    <input id="testButton" type="button" value="Add" /><br />
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.MyStrings, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "testListbox", style = "width:100px;" })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#testButton").click(function () {
            var value = $("#testTestbox").val();
            $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>').appendTo("#testListbox");
        });
    </script>
}
```

However, the MyStrings property is always blank when I submit. Am I making a mistake somewhere which could be fixed with a small amend, or is what I am trying to do just not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this..

> ```
> $("<option value='"+ value + "' selected='selected'>" + value +"</option>").appendTo("#testListbox");
> ```

selected='selected' will select the options which entered by user and binds to model property "MyStrings"

Answer (score 0):

After adding values to the listbox, select the values from listbox before submitting it to the controller.

I think you are submitting the form  without selecting values from listbox...